# How do I remove duplicate dicts (with nested dicts) from a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set, duplicates

I have a list of dictionaries which contain nested dictionaries, like this:

```
v0 = [ { 'a': 1, 'b': { 'c': 3 } },
       { 'a': 1, 'b': { 'c': 3 }, 'd': 4 },
       { 'a': 1 },
       { 'a': 1, 'b': { 'c': 3 } } ]
```

How can I remove duplicate list elements, with a result like:

```
v1 = [ { 'a': 1, 'b': { 'c': 3 } },
       { 'a': 1, 'b': { 'c': 3 }, 'd': 4 },
       { 'a': 1 } ]
```

I don't care about order, I just want the set of all elements. I've seen numerous similar questions, but the answers only work with simple dictionaries in a list, not nested dictionaries. For example:

```
v1 = [dict(t) for t in set([tuple(d.items()) for d in v0])]
```

This would work if the dictionaries were not nested, but because they are, I get the error "TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> v0 = [ { 'a': 1, 'b': { 'c': 3 } },
...        { 'a': 1, 'b': { 'c': 3 }, 'd': 4 },
...        { 'a': 1 },
...        { 'a': 1, 'b': { 'c': 3 } } ]
>>> out = []
>>> for v in v0:
...     if v not in out:
...         out.append(v)
...         
>>> out
[{'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 3}}, {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 3}, 'd': 4}, {'a': 1}]
```

Comment: It's important to note that this is O(n^2), while a more efficient solution can achieve O(n).

Comment: I ended up using this. Fortunately my list is small enough that the perf hit doesn't matter, and I find this to be very readable.

Comment: @univerio: How is this a O(n^2) solution? `for v in v0` is O(n) and `if v not in out` is O(1).

Comment: Because "not in" for lists is O(n), not O(1).

Answer (score 3):

First, consider whether there's a simpler idea that's good enough.

If your set of dictionaries isn't that large, the last one is really easy—a `list` already works just like a `set`, except that each search is linear instead of constant-time. So, the same code will take quadratic time instead of linear, but it will work, and it's dead-simple, so if that's acceptable, just do it.

If your set of dictionaries can get pretty big, there's still a relatively easy alternative: tree-based collections like the ones in [`blist`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/) or [`bintrees`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bintrees/) can search in logarithmic time. So, the same code will take log-linear time instead of linear—which is usually good enough—and again will work, and as dead simple.

If even log-linear is too slow, then you need a frozen dict type, and a recursive freezing function. But there are implementations on PyPI and ActiveState, such as [`frozendict`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/frozendict/0.3), and it's not too hard to write one yourself.

In fact, you're halfway there. `set([tuple(d.items()] for d in v0])` does a single level of freezing, and fakes a frozen dict with a set of tuples (which won't work for many use cases, but is fine for yours). So you just need to do the same thing recursively.

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy with a quadratic algorithm, then

```
uniq = [x for n, x in enumerate(v0) if v0.index(x) == n]
```

Otherwise something like

```
import json
uniq = {json.dumps(x, sort_keys=True):x for x in v0}.values()
```